# Proof Technique

Tags: general-topology

This is a two part question.  I was given the following proof technique during a lecture.

---

Given that $X$ is a connected topological space prove that $X$ has property $P$ for all $x\in X$ by the following method.

1) Define $A=\{x:P(x) \text{ is true}\}$ and $B=\{x:P(x) \text{ is false}\}$

2)  Prove that $A$ is not empty

3)  Show that both $A$ and $B$ are open in $X$ then since $X=A\cup B$ and $A\neq \emptyset$ then $B=\emptyset$ by the connectedness of $X$.

---

My questions are, did I note the proof technique correctly and what's a good example of using this technique.

Comment: Yes.  Example: pages 39-40 of this book: https://books.google.com/books?id=xUHDAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA241&dq=cartan+elementary+theory+of+analytic+functions&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjVpryU5-fOAhXBMx4KHdc1AFkQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=connected&f=false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you did note the proof "technique" correctly. The reason why I put 'technique' in quotations, is that that it is not really a formal system of logic, so laid out.

I would like to elaborate. Your third step is quite dense, and I think it contains your main questions. What is really going on is a proof by construction:

1. Use the fact that the only clopen sets in a connected space are the whole space, $X$, and $\emptyset$.
2. Now, $X = A \cup B$, where $A$, and $B$ are so defined, by construction; and, particularly, $A \cap B = \emptyset$.
3. Use the fact that both $A$ and $B$ are open to conclude that they must be the whole space, or the empty set, via (1) .
4. Show that $A$ is non-empty; this implies that $A = X$.
5. Therefore, for all $x \in X = A$, $P(x)$ is true.